# How to unit test pessimistic locking with Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to test whether the **`FooRepository.lock()`** works, after someone called the `lock()`, others calling it should be wait.

The following is my best try, it doesn't work. I believe the reason is both `entityManger` and `fooRepository` are participating in the same transaction.

How to call the `lock()` from another transaction? Or any suggestion for unit-testing the pessimistic lock? Thanks!!

FooRepositoryTest:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.LockModeType;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class FooRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;    

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Test
    public void lockTest() {
        // given
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setName("foo-name");

        UUID fooId = fooRepository.save(foo).getFooId();
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();

        // when
        Foo savedFoo = fooRepository.findOne(fooId);
        fooRepository.lock(savedFoo);

        // then
        // I want something like this to be lock wait,
        // something to confirm the above fooRepository.lock() work
        entityManager.getEntityManager().lock(savedFoo, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    }

}
```

class Foo:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Foo {  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID fooId;

    private String name;

    public UUID getFooId() {
        return fooId;
    }

    public void setFooId(UUID fooId) {
        this.fooId = fooId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

class FooApplication:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FooApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FooApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

class FooRepository:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, UUID>, FooRepositoryCustom {  
}
```

class FooRepositoryCustom:

```
package com.example.demo;

public interface FooRepositoryCustom {  
    public void lock(Foo foo);  
}
```

class FooRepositoryImpl:

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.LockModeType;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class FooRepositoryImpl implements FooRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void lock(Foo foo) {
        entityManager.lock(foo, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why? `EntityManager.lock` is part of the JPA spec so it is the responsibility of the JPA provider to ensure that it works according to the spec ([example](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/locking/LockModeTest.java)). If it doesn't (work according to the spec), there is nothing we can do as end users any way until the provider fixes the problem.

Comment: @manish, @GhostCat, my test target is `fooRepository.lock(savedFoo)`, not `EntityManager.lock()`, sorry to make you guys confused. I have added `//given`, `//when`, `//then` to show what is the SUT.
The reason to test this is I want to put all `Foo` related data manipulation on the `FooRepository`, and on need level `FooRepository` will be mocked.

Comment: @GhostCat, thx for reminding, I will add a comment to your answer

Answer (score 1):

You are getting unit testing **wrong**.

You do **not** write unit test to exercise functionality implemented by some 3rd party framework. Unit tests are for *your* units!

In other words: you do not need to verify that *locking* works as expected. Your unit does:

```
entityManager.lock(foo, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

so the *only* thing you could consider testing here: making sure that the entity manager `lock()` method is called with the expected parameters.

Meaning: verify that your code does use the framework as you think it should be used - but don't get into testing other peoples code! You see - what would you do when your unit test shows that the framework is wrong ... you can't change that! (sure, you can write a bug report then)

Disclaimer: there might be special situations where you *assume* that some 3rd party product has a bug - then it might be very useful to write a unit test to test this assumption. So that you can later run the unit test against a new version of that product to see if the bug is still present.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but `EntityManager.lock()` is not the method under test in this case.
Off course I am not trying to test the `EntityManager.lock()`, what the test could reveal is whether I am making the Foo correct to be called with `EntityManager.lock()`.

Comment: I am still looking for a way to test MY code. Yes, I am calling a 3rd party framework, but it's now part of my system, and I need to test the system as a whole at some point before I deliver the software. So either I can test it manually, or automatically, I am still looking for a solution of the latter.
I also write test code to test my SQL statements, to see whether they work as expected, and when they are not, I will try to work around them. When a SQL statement is 100% correct but a database fail to execute as expected, saying nothing I can do with the database is not a solution, right?

Comment: I am not sure what else to say: *your* code is `entityManager.lock()` . The only thing that you can reasonable verify about that: make `entityManager` a **mocked** object - and then verify that the **lock** method was invoked as you would expect it.

Comment: I understand your point, and yes, i did actually mocking `FooRepository` to verify whether the system did call it. But I still want to test it automatically, may be the code not call it with `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`, may be with a wrong entity, THAT part is my code, not `EntityManage.lock()`

Comment: I am sorry. My knowledge of Spring doesn't go deep enough to give proper advise then. In case you dont get better answers - feel free to drop me a comment next week. I might be willing to put up a bounty on your question on a good day. Beyond that: I added the java tag, maybe that will drag in enough attention to get to a better answer!

Comment: With all respect I don't agree with the idea that testing this is wrong. This kind of test (no matter if you call it unit test or integration test) should be present in the system. How else would you know, if the functionality does what you think it does? You are not testing the framework, you are testing your understanding of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Testing pessimistic locking handling with an integration test is important (may I say mandatory?) for two reasons:

- There is a good chance that the LockTimeout parameter is not correctly configured (by Oracle and PostgreSQL it is by default infinite time) and this could have a dramatic impact on the stability/performance of the system in production;
- The JPA implementation for pessimistic locking by most RDBMS is very limited because the 6 internal LockTimeout parameters differ; Testing against an in-memory database only could be not enough and would require special considerations.

In the blog post [Testing Pessimistic Locking Handling With SpringBoot and JPA](https://blog.mimacom.com/testing-pessimistic-locking-handling-spring-boot-jpa) you could:

- Read more about pessimistic locking handling;
- And you could find **GitHub examples** for testing against Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL and Apache Derby.

*The Spring Framework is used only as an example. You could easly adapt the tests for every other framework.*

Comment: can you explain more the first bullet option? When should I define a LockTimeout parameter for a PostgreSQL Database running a microservice architecture of spring boot apps e.g.? What should that value be?